# SSL On Server Doesn't Work, On Local Machine Works Fine

Tags: java, ssl, cxf

This is more of a general java SSL question than anything...

I am using CXF to connect to a secure web service. When I run it on my local Windows development machine, it connects and works, however, once I deployed it to my application server (glassfish 3.1) it no longer works. I get this:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://vendorUrl: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1458)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1443)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:659)
```

I've tried adding the cert to the domain\config\cacerts.jks file, to the lib\security\cacerts file, etc. but since that has been asked many times I'm not asking why that isn't working (though, I'd like to know why).

What has me confused is, why would this work on my local dev machine without adding anything to any keystores? I mean, I didn't connect to their URL's via a browser, I didn't add anything - it just worked, the first time, from Eclipse. Why?

Comment: It's possible that the two machines you're using have different JREs configured with different `cacerts`. List their contents with `keytool`.

Answer (score 0):

> What has me confused is, why would this work on my local dev machine
>   without adding anything to any keystores? I mean, I didn't connect to
>   their URL's via a browser, I didn't add anything - it just worked, the
>   first time, from Eclipse.

The information you post are not helpful (this is the least I can say).
What you are saying could happen in only 2 cases:
1) The server uses a certificate signed by a trusted CA already in java's truststore `cacert` (e.g. Verisign)
2) You have enabled the `anonymous` ciphers suites

Since when you deploy it in a different machine you have handshake exception complaining about validation, I guess we can rule out (1).
From what you describe it seems that (2) is not possible either, since you haven't enabled anonymous ciphers suites.
So.... please update your post with more accurate information. Also debugging info from the good and bad case

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to SSL, so I wasn't sure what would be helpful. I'll dig into it a bit more. FWIW, this app uses wssj in addition to SSL, maybe this has something to do with it, I'm not sure.